# Reseting zoom and pan when updating chart in livecharts

Tags: wpf, vb.net, livecharts

I'm using beto-rodriguez's livecharts for VB.NET/WPF, where I'm setting the source data in the code-behind and showing a plot when the user clicks a button.

I have enabled the zooming feature on my chart using `chart.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.X`. My issue here if that if I zoom to 150% and pan away from the point (0,0) for example, and I load a new plot on the same control, the zoom is not reset, as the new plot will be zoomed 150% and panned by the same value.

Is there a way to reset the chart zoom and pan every time its `.Series` value is reset ?

By the way, my x-axis contains dates, therefore, setting the min and max values wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is right, there you are forcing the range of your axis, but you can also let the chart to try to auto scale setting your axis limits to `double.NaN`

From the site: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Zooming%20and%20panning

```
cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].MinValue = double.NaN;
cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].MaxValue = double.NaN;
cartesianChart1.AxisY[0].MinValue = double.NaN;
cartesianChart1.AxisY[0].MaxValue = double.NaN;
```

Comment: This is even better than the solution I found, I'll be using it for my project. Also, I have one last small request : I would like to know if there's a way to limit the panning to the actual plot, and not have a white space appear if I drag the plot beyond it's min/max value. By the way, your library is a blessing for WPF charting.

Comment: As an addition to this - in case you're using Bindings for MinValue and MaxValue, you must set Mode=TwoWay. Otherwise setting these to double.NaN will do nothing if you used the scroll wheel meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
    xAxis.Labels = labels

    ' Run these two lines every time the chart is updated
    xAxis.MinValue = 0
    xAxis.MaxValue = labels.Count - 1
```

Where `xAxis` is the name of my `Axis` control and `labels` is a list of strings containing the x-axis dates.